# Can't Find Winforms Trackbar Control in VS2008

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I've been looking around the toolbox but I can't seem to find a trackbar control.

Is it hidden somewhere? Or is it just not available on the designer and instead I have to code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the All Windows Forms toolbox:

[image]

Comment: Didn't notice that tab. It was collapsed and I couldn't find it anywhere else! Maybe they didn't put it in one of the more specific tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Right click in the `Controls` pannel and select `Choose Items ...`.

Then you can scrolldown to select it and make sure it is enabled.